# What's the different between pwd and root in struct of task_struct?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

the sched.h in Linux-0.12:

```
struct task_struct {
/* these are hardcoded - don't touch */
        long state;     /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped */
        long counter;
        long priority;
        long signal;
        struct sigaction sigaction[32];
        long blocked;   /* bitmap of masked signals */
/* various fields */
        int exit_code;
        unsigned long start_code,end_code,end_data,brk,start_stack;
        long pid,pgrp,session,leader;
        int     groups[NGROUPS];
        /* 
         * pointers to parent process, youngest child, younger sibling,
         * older sibling, respectively.  (p->father can be replaced with 
         * p->p_pptr->pid)
         */
        struct task_struct      *p_pptr, *p_cptr, *p_ysptr, *p_osptr;
        unsigned short uid,euid,suid;
        unsigned short gid,egid,sgid;
        unsigned long timeout,alarm;
        long utime,stime,cutime,cstime,start_time;
        struct rlimit rlim[RLIM_NLIMITS];
        unsigned int flags;     /* per process flags, defined below */
        unsigned short used_math;
/* file system info */
        int tty;                /* -1 if no tty, so it must be signed */
        unsigned short umask;
        struct m_inode * pwd;
        struct m_inode * root;
        struct m_inode * executable;
        struct m_inode * library;
        unsigned long close_on_exec;
        struct file * filp[NR_OPEN];
/* ldt for this task 0 - zero 1 - cs 2 - ds&ss */
        struct desc_struct ldt[3];
/* tss for this task */
        struct tss_struct tss;
};
```

What's different between `struct m_inode * root` and `struct m_inode * pwd` ?
Thank you.

Comment: are t talking about the very early linux kernel version ?

Comment: Don't think that `0.12` is used today. There is a lot of changes even between `3.0` and `3.2` as far as I know.

Comment: @Uday I'm a new one. so I learn the kernel from 0.12

Comment: perhaps you should look at kernel version 2.4 or more as I believe the documentation for previous kernel versions are very difficult to get and of course as Alex said there are quite a lot of changes may be you can find few resources of old linux here http://www.oldlinux.org/

Answer (score 1):

The pwd is a dentry struct.  A dentry is what maps file names to inode numbers.  The pwd is just the current directory you are in.  The root, is the root dentry, so I assume it is the root directory /.

http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch12lev1sec10

Answer (score 1):

the pwd in such structs presents current working directory, usually not the same thing as the command pwd in Linux.

If you want a example, use  ps to get a pid XXX of a running process in terminal, and cd /proc/XXX/,there are root and cwd(current working directory) of the process.

Answer (score 1):

`cwd` is the current working directory which you can change with `chdir()`. `root` is the root directory that can be changed with `chroot()` (look up chroot jail).